# how to synchronize two subscriptions so that one starts only when other emits

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm developing an angular app, I have this situation: an observable which signals that some data have been fetched from remote (`dataFetchedEvent$`) and a form which uses that remote data and listens user changes (`formChanges$`).

```
   const dataFetchedEvent$ = this.event.asObservable()
      .pipe(
        tap((fetchedData) => {
          this.createFormControls(fetchedData); // creates the reactive form control based on the data fecthed from remote
        }),
        takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed) // fired when in the ngOnDestroy of the component
      );

    const formChanges$ = this.form.valueChanges // listen form changes
      .pipe(
        switchMap((formDataRaw) => this.formatData(formDataRaw)), // transform data
        takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed)
      );

    dataFetchedEvent$.subscribe();

    formChanges$.subscribe(
      (formattedFormData) => {
        // do stuff...
      }
    );
```

With this code all works but when is fired `dataFetchedEvent$` the  `formChanges$` subscription is invoked every single time a control is changed by `this.createFormControls(fetchedData)` and I want to avoid it.
My goal is to listen form changes only after the form controls were created or updated.
I tried multiple solutions but each has some limit:

with **skipUntil**

```
   const formChanges$ = this.form.valueChanges // listen form changes
      .pipe(
        skipUntil(dataFetchedEvent$),
        switchMap((formDataRaw) => this.formatData(formDataRaw)), // transform data
        takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed)
      );
```

This solution avoids the multiple emissions of `formChanges$` stream while the controls are created and works when the component is destroyed an recreated (for example when the user changes page and returns) but for the behavior of skipUntil the `dataFetchedEvent$` is unsubscribed after the first emission and I have some cases in which the `dataFetchedEvent$` must emit again and update the form controls.

with **concat**

```
   const formChanges$ = this.form.valueChanges // listen form changes
      .pipe(
        switchMap((formDataRaw) => this.formatData(formDataRaw)), // transform data
        tap((formattedFormData) => {
          // do stuff...
        }),
        takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed)
      );

    concat(dataFetchedEvent$, formChanges$).subscribe();
```

In this situation the `formChanges$` stream is never subscribed, I think this happens because dataFetchedEvent$ don't complete.

with **combineLatest**

```
combineLatest(dataFetchedEvent$, formChanges$).subscribe([val1, val2] => { // do stuff... });
```

It's not that I'm looking for because the formChanges$ stream still emits when I am creating the controls.

with **mergeMap or switchMap**

```
const dataFetchedEvent$ = this.event.asObservable()
  .pipe(
    tap((fetchedData) => {
      this.createFormControls(fetchedData); // creates the reactive form control based on the data fecthed from remote
    }),
    mergeMap(() => formChanges$),
    takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed) // fired when in the ngOnDestroy of the component
  );

  dataFetchedEvent$.subscribe();
```

This works the first time or if the component is destroyed and recreated, but if the `dataFetchedEvent$` emits again after the first time `formChanges$` emits every time the form controls are updated. With `switchMap` the behavior is the same.

Which is the best approach to reach my goal?

------ EDIT ------

In my example the code was generic and simplified.

Here are the form controls

```
form = this.fb.group({
    tourLength: this.fb.group({
      length: [false]
    }),
    types: this.fb.group({
      type: [false]
    }),
    categories: this.fb.group({}),
    languages: this.fb.group({
      lang: [false]
    }),
    prices: this.fb.group({
      opt: [false]
    })
  });
```

The only group that changes is categories, when `dataFetchedEvent$` emits means that new categories was fecthed from remote and I update the controls with `_createControlsCategories()` which is the previous `createFormControls`

```
private _createControlsCategories(categories) {
   const categoriesGroup: FormGroup = this.filterForm.get('categories') as FormGroup;
   categoriesGroup.controls = {};
   for (const cat of categories) {         
      categoriesGroup.addControl(cat.id_remote, new FormControl(false));
   }
```

}

every category is binded to a checkbox in the view.

Comment: What do you mean by "emits again after the first time formChanges$ emits every time the form controls are updated" 
Because the last solution with switchMap looks really well

Comment: In some scenarios the dataFetchedEvent$ can emit more than one time. The first time , when the component is created, all works as I would like: while the form controls are created the formChanges$ stream don't emit because is not still subscribed. But while the user is still in the same component (he didn't change page) If the conditions are met for dataFetchedEvent$ stream to emit again , the formChanges$ is now listening so it emits values while I'm updating the form controls with the new fetched data and this is the situation I would like to avoid. Hope I explained myself.

Comment: why don't you try disabling the form before `createFormControls` and enabling it after creating/updating all the controls

Comment: What do you mean with "enabling and disabling"? You mean I have to unsubscribe `formChanges$`  before `createFormControls` and resubscribe after?

Comment: check this https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disable

Comment: @wolverine Your approach seemed to be simple and clear , I tried it out but the formChanges$ still to emit while the form is disabled, as if it ignored that. I used `this.form.disable({onlySelf: false, emitEvent: false});` before `createFormControls` and `this.form.enable()` after...

Comment: sorry, it won't work, the flag is to not emit event at the time of disabling, but it will emit after that

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
const dataFetchedEvent$ = this.event.asObservable()
  .pipe(
    tap((fetchedData) => {
      this.createFormControls(fetchedData); 
    }));

  dataFetchedEvent$
    .pipe(
      switchMap(() => formChanges$.pipe(takeUntil(dataFetchedEvent)),
      takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed)
  ).subscribe();
```

Comment: I tried but as in my example with switchMap/mergeMap , if dataFetchedEvent$ emits again after the first time while I'm updating the controls the formChanges$ stream emits value.

Comment: @berno Could you send the body of the registerPostOrderHooks? I want to check how the formChanges$ is created

Comment: sorry I never use it before, can you explain me what I have to do?

Comment: sorry, some bad copy paste. I want body of your createFormControls

Comment: I updated my answer to show you the form and the real createFormControls

Comment: I see only that my solution require recreating the formChanges$ because it will stops emit after the next dataFetchedEvent.
Maybe try the easiest way which is:
```filter(() => !!this.controlsCreation)```
in the first or second pipe